# PostgreSQL: Call Function WIth JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

As seen here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-callproc.html

```
// Turn transactions off.
con.setAutoCommit(false);
// Procedure call.
CallableStatement upperProc = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call upper( ? ) }");
upperProc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
upperProc.setString(2, "lowercase to uppercase");
upperProc.execute();
String upperCased = upperProc.getString(1);
upperProc.close();
```

Can I instead do:

```
// Turn transactions off.
con.setAutoCommit(false);
// Procedure call.
CallableStatement upperProc = con.prepareCall("{call upper( ? ) }");
upperProc.setString(2, "lowercase to uppercase");
upperProc.execute();
upperProc.close();
```

I just remove the ? before call upper. My query just inserts so I dont need a value. I want to keep it in this forma becuase mysql also uses this format thus I can reuse a lot of code in JAVA.

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: In general, you can call functions with `SELECT` without the need for `CallableStatement` (that's how they would be called in `psql`).

Comment: Just use `select upper(?)`. No need for `CallableStatement` in Postgres

Comment: I would like to use call because I also have the sampe procedure name in MySQL. Thus I can reuse code. Postgresql uses the first code snipet as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JavaDoc for CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) shows a syntax without a return value:

```
   {call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}
```

so if PgJDBC doesn't accept it that's a bug.

You can just leave out the `? =`.

Comment: Not necessarily, if there is a return value, than AFAIK it is an error not to declare a parameter to retrieve it.

Comment: I would have a r return value but I return null. Basically I just want to do INSERT statements.